# AngularJS, gulp, typescript: How to not have .ts and .js littering the same directory?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp

I'm exploring the Angular2 examples from their programming guides.  One example is the code available from [the Angular2 Routing tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). The code itself isn't important, it works and works for me in my compiling environment.

What I'm having issue with is that the Typescript and Javascript files both end up in the same directory.  *For example, I have both app.module.ts and app.module.js in the same place.*  I'd like to separate the compiled files from the source Typescript files.

Here is my typescript.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "aot/*",
    "app/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

In my index.html I have `<base href="/">`, and some `<script src="path/myfile.js"></script>` references.  I'm hoping not to have to change those.

Thanks,
Jerome.

Answer (score 0):

use "outDir" to specify where the output files should go.

in case you are using vs-code editor & dont want to set outDir, you can use below settings

```
"**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"},
"**/*.js.map": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}
```

Comment: I can change to ("outDir": "out"), but that doesn't get the web site to render (that puts the out directory at the same level as the app directory).  I get HTTP 404 errors on app/main.js.  Try clearing your browser cache and see.  I've tried a variety configurations for outDir and <base href="..."> with no good results.  Can you complete your answer?